# Issue with player jumping

Tags: c++, double, codeblocks

I'm a little bit of a new programmer, kinda doing relatively basic stuff. Over the past while (although I haven't been working on it very often) I've been, with the help of SDL, been making a 2D game. Right now, I'm working on the code for causing the player to jump when pressing the w key (controls are wsad). I quickly realized that I couldn't keep the speed constant because this would cause the jump to go more like the graph of y=-|x| than y=-x^2, which would look more like an actual jump than the former. Here's the bits of code that make it work.

```
    //The part which happens when the jump key is pressed (w)
    case SDLK_w:
        if(InAir != true) {
            StartOfJump = PlayerYCoord;
            InAir = true;
            velocity = 0.01;
            break;
        }
    //And skip to a different part.
    if(InAir == true) {
      if(StartOfJump - PlayerYCoord < JumpHeight) {
        PlayerYCoord = PlayerYCoord - velocity;
        velocity = velocity * velocity;
```

velocity is there to make the speed that the Y coord of the player increases, increase exponentially. Right now, it's set to 0.01 at the start of the program.

JumpHeight is the number of pixels the player jumps. This is for the purpose of being able to modify it with ease. As it is, JumpHeight is set to 100 pixels.

StartOfJump is there to ensure that the jump is cut off at the right point, because while at the moment the map for the game is flat I don't expect to keep it that way.

And PlayerYCoord is fairly self-explanatory, but basically it's the Y coordinate of the player on the plane. it is a double.

And yes, I know that right now there is no code for falling. That's not really important when I can't even get the rising part.

Anyway, I'm not really certain why, but for some reason the player's position just increases by one pixel on the pressing of the w key, and it doesn't do anything else. I tried modifying the code to say this

```
    if(InAir == true) {
      if(StartOfJump - PlayerYCoord < JumpHeight) {
        //PlayerYCoord = PlayerYCoord - 0.1;
        PlayerYCoord = PlayerYCoord - velocity;
        velocity = velocity * velocity;
        cout << fixed << setprecision(4);
        cout << "The velocity is" << velocity << " " << endl;
```

Uuuunfortunately, it starts by printing out 0.0001 then prints 0.000 forever. But that's not right, is it?... The value of velocity is 0.01... so, I changed that last line to say this:

```
     cout << "The velocity is" << velocity * 100 << " " << endl;
```

Sure enough, it output 0.0100 and then output 0.0000 infinitely like last time. I'm honestly unsure what's causing this issue, but I think it has something to do with the fact that the player's Y coordinate only increases by one pixel then stops.

I'm probably making a really stupid mistake that can be fixed very easily. Anyway, if there's any other bits of code that I need to include (first time on programming forums, I haven't quite got this stuff nailed down yet) I'd be happy to include it. Thanks in advance for the help!

P.S. In case any of my code is system-dependent, I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, 32 bit.

Comment: There's no code for rising either.

Comment: PlayerYCoord = PlayerYCoord - velocity;

Comment: Could you post the entire message queue or whatever function you process key presses in?

Comment: Remember, the SDL coordinate plane is flipped across y=x.

Comment: That goes up 0.01 units. Then it goes up 0.0001 units. Then...

Comment: If I change the code that SHOULD make it rise to 'PlayerYCoord--;' then it works fine.

Comment: Ignacio, thank you. I think I understand now. Silly me forgot that squaring numbers under 1 makes them smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You've implemented gravity incorrectly. You need to start off with an upwards velocity. You then need to subtract the downwards acceleration from gravity each unit of time. This will handle both rising *and* falling. Your code does... strange things.

```
velocity = 50
each unit of time while player is in the air:
  playerY -= velocity
  velocity -= acceleration
```

Comment: Yeh, thanks. I feel silly now for such a little mistake. I should have no troubles fixing it now. Thanks for the help, I'm sure I'll have it functioning in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite agree with the above solution.

Your player should always be affected by gravity, right? Even if we are on the ground we are affected by gravity?

Always affect the player by gravity but when we press a jump button or so, add counter force that flings the player upwards (but only once) and then the gravity will outtake this force and push the player down.

The boolean `InAir`should only determine if the player can jump again. So if we are in the air we shouldn't be able to execute another jump command. But if we are grounded `(InAir = false )` Then we should be able to jump again.

This also makes it more efficient to add double jump or such.

Happy coding!